# Sort MySQL data using a variable

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I've come in peace lol.

I have a question how do I achieve this kind of algorithm(i'll just use an example im bad at english)

in index.php page. i have sent a get method `(term=dog&name=john)`

and in process.php how do I sort my data using this get method data where in the page will display all the "term=dog" and the first that will display is the "name=john" followed by whatever (name="whatever").

the page display example would be

```
dog
**john**

dog
peter

dog
jane
```

my fail attempt only shows all the list of dogs but i cannot specify what goes first in this case is "john"

heres my failed result

```
dog
peter

dog
jame

dog
**john**
```

it sorts on according to its ID property in the table different from what i want it to be.

```
SELECT * FROM animal WHERE race = '$term' ORDER BY '$name'
```

This is all the code i have so far i haven't started to sort it because i don't know

Comment: i'm sorry but this makes no sense to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems to me you want to get all rows where `race` = '$term' and if `name` = '$name', then put that row at the top of the result set. You can use this solution:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     animal 
WHERE    race = '$term'
ORDER BY CASE name WHEN '$name' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, name
```

Comment: @anoldgangstah After the "top" row, how do you want the subsequent rows to be ordered? Alphabetically?

Comment: can you please explain what is meant by those `then 0 else 1 end`

Comment: in terms of names yes alphabetically.

Comment: @anoldgangstah, have a look at the [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression. It basically says if `name` = `your input name`, put a `0` into the row, otherwise, put a `1`. It then orders on this number in ***ascending*** order, so the name that equaled your parameter is placed first since we put a `0` in its row.

Comment: man i cant thank you enough you saved my life! i will just spam check button and up arrow!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM animal WHERE race = '$term' ORDER BY (name = '$name') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT race, name, IF(name = 'john', 1, 0) AS o FROM animal WHERE race = 'dog' ORDER BY o DESC;
```

Should do it for you, if I understand correctly.  You want all rows WHERE race = 'dog' but with a specified name at the top.